# Select lines that are no 'islands'

Tags: postgis, postgresql, linestring, st-touches

I have one table with several `linestrings`. I want to select all these `linestrings`, that do not touch any other `linestrings`, thus are "islands", are not connected to any other `linestring`. How would I do that in PostGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A performant SQL based solution is to check if an intersection `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  linestrings AS l
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      linestrings AS sl
    WHERE
      l.id <> sl.id
      AND
      ST_Intersects(sl.geom, l.geom)
  )
;
```

to *select* only isolated geometries, or

```
SELECT
  *,
  EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      linestrings AS sl
    WHERE
      l.id <> sl.id
      AND
      ST_Intersects(sl.geom, l.geom)
  ) AS touches
FROM
  linestrings AS l
;
```

to add a `BOOL` column indicating if a geometry touches others.

---

Note that, in order to scale this you may want to consider using `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` with `minpoints = 2`; isolated geometries will then get a `NULL` assigned as function return value.

Comment: What is the `<>` operator doing?

Comment: @Stophface *greater than or smaller than* - i.e. *not equal to* (`!=`), to exclude self-intersection.